# TSQL OrderBy Offset issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query that almost makes what I want:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT D.Id from MtdMdl_HierarchicalObject D
where D.Name LIKE '%R%'

SELECT B.* FROM MtdMdl_Item A
OUTER apply (SELECT * FROM MtdMdl_Item as C where a.Id=c.Id) as B
WHERE A.Owner in 
(
    SELECT D.Id from MtdMdl_HierarchicalObject D
    where D.Name LIKE '%R%'
)
order by Id offset 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
GO
```

Unfortunately I would like the Order By Id Fetch New 3 Rows to be applied on each object returned by:

```
SELECT D.Id from MtdMdl_HierarchicalObject D
where D.Name LIKE '%R%'
```

Because the current script apply the Paging on the whole result of the previous statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not skipping any row and just getting 3 rows why bother using OFFSET at all ??? just Use TOP clause

```
SELECT B.* 
FROM MtdMdl_Item A OUTER APPLY 
                    (SELECT TOP 3 * 
                     FROM MtdMdl_Item  
                      where Id= a.Id) as B
WHERE A.Owner in 
(
    SELECT D.Id from MtdMdl_HierarchicalObject D
    where D.Name LIKE '%R%'
)
order by Id
```

In this case you could do something like this...

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT B.*, A.ID , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY A.ID) 
FROM MtdMdl_Item A OUTER APPLY 
                    (SELECT  * 
                     FROM MtdMdl_Item  
                      where Id= a.Id) as B
WHERE A.Owner in 
(
    SELECT D.Id from MtdMdl_HierarchicalObject D
    where D.Name LIKE '%R%'
)
order by Id
) Q
WHERE RN >= LowerList  AND RN <= UpperLimit
```

Comment: I guess OP wants new 3 rows for each DB round trip, simple putting a top ill return the same 3 rows. If my guess is correct OP ill need to keep and pass some kind of StartFromRow_N parameter from app to the query.

Comment: @jean ID OFFSET 0 means OP isnt skipping any rows. so it will make more sense to just use TOP clause rather then OFFSET.

Comment: It's kind of my fault, in this case there's 0 in the offset but the real intent is to use paging, so I can have non null offset.

Comment: @Nock have a look now, in this way you have the felxibility of setting Upper Limit AND Lower Limit. Not sure if I have partitioned on the right Column but you get the main Idea what I am actually, im sure you can tweak it a bit further if need .